# My filter function crashes if no result found

Tags: ios, swift, filter

Here is the code :

```
private func filter(searchText: String) -> [MICountry] {
    filteredList.removeAll()

    sections.forEach { (section) -> () in
        section.countries.forEach({ (country) -> () in
            let result = country.name.compare(searchText, options: [.CaseInsensitiveSearch, .DiacriticInsensitiveSearch], range: searchText.startIndex ..< searchText.endIndex)
            if (result == .OrderedSame) {
                filteredList.append(country)
            }

        })
    }

    return filteredList
}
```

My Country and section classes are as follows:

```
class MICountry: NSObject {
    let name: String
    var section: Int?

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct MISection {
    var countries: [MICountry] = []

    mutating func addCountry(country: MICountry) {
        countries.append(country)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your error.

Comment: Could you show us what sort of error you get? Do you see something in the console for instance? That might help us solve your problem

Comment: problem can be in range

Comment: I solved it guys, and yes the error was in the range. The case when country name length is less that the search text length. I added this condition : if country.name.characters.count >= searchText.characters.count

Comment: then up vote the comment )